# Random Variable in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Can we use a variable in the minimum value in the Random Variable like:[image]

It always give only 0. MIN and MAX are defined in a .csv data file. I am trying to get a random number between 1-15 from load generator-1 and 16-30 from load generator-2

Thanks,
N

Answer (score 1):

What do you use for reading the values from CSV? If it's CSV Data Set Config - it won't work because according to the [JMeter Test Element Execution Order](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder):

1. Random Variable is executed **before** any Sampler
2. CSV Data Set Config reads next line from the CSV file on each Sampler iteration

If you have CSV file which looks like:

```
1,15
```

You can amend your Random Variable configuration to use [__CSVRead() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead), something like:

[image]

Textual representation just in case:

```
${__CSVRead(test.csv,0)}
${__CSVRead(test.csv,1)}
```

you will get the result you're looking for as [JMeter Functions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions) are being evaluated just at where they're found.

Comment: Hi Dmitri, thx for the response but this will not achieve what I am looking for because I am trying to have one range for load generator-1 and another range for generator-2. Here if the file name is specified in the script, then both injectors will go through the same file set.

Comment: How about copying different files to different load generators?

Comment: That is what we have at the moment - same file name in both the generators but the contents/range is different but I was using CSV Data Set Config. As per your suggestion if i remove CSV data set config completely and use only the CSVRead function do I need to give the complete path?

Comment: Whatever you want, either complete or relative, but the file needs to be present

Answer (score -1):

You surely can use variables to provide Minimum and Maximum values for `Random Variable element`.

As to why it always returns '0':

I assume that MIN and MAX variables are not initialized. You could check that by adding `Debug Sampler` before `Random Variable` and viewing the actual values in `View Result Tree` element.
If they are indeed not initialized I suggest you should check that .csv data file is correctly read by `CSV Data Set Config`.

Comment: Hi George, I have placed the file File.csv in load generator-1 as: 
MIN, MAX
1,15

same file in generator-2 as:
MIN,MAX
16,30